# Use two WP Query in template

Tags: php, query

I have two different custom post type on my WP website, one is 'item_a' and another one is 'item_b'. I want to display all posts in 'item_a' and 'item_b' using WP_Query object, but I can't use two WP_Query objects at a time.So In this case, what should I do? Thanks to all genius who viewed this question!!!

```
    <?php
  $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'item_a' ) );
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>                    
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
       <!-- show item_a posts -->
  <?php else : ?>
       <!-- show 404 error here -->
        <p>404 error</p>
  <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
      $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'item_b' ) );
      if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>                    
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
           <!-- show item_b posts -->
      <?php else : ?>
           <!-- show 404 error here -->
            <p>404 error</p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Your `item_a` and `item_b` must be a custom post type.

Comment: yes my 'item_a' and 'item_b' are the custom post type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use two instances of `WP_Query` as long as you call the `wp_reset_postdata` function, just like you did in your code.

You're missing the `while` statement and `posts_per_page` for `WP_Query` array argument item.

```
<?php
 $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'item_a', 'posts_per_page' => -1 /** Show all **/ ) );
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>                    
   <!-- show item_a posts -->
   <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <!-- show 404 error here -->
  <p>404 error</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
  $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'item_b', 'posts_per_page' => -1 /** Show all **/ ) );
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
  <!-- show item_b posts -->
  <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <!-- show 404 error here -->
  <p>404 error</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```